# Why does Matlab iso image get mounted as read-only?

Tags: mount, iso, matlab

I have been trying to install Matlab on Ubuntu.

The issue starts even prior to the installation, as mounting the .iso file results in the following error:

```
mount: block device /home/marta/Downloads/R2013a_UNIX.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

When typing `blkid` I get:

```
/dev/loop1: LABEL="MATHWORKS_R2013A" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="CB61-A2F3" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="3a6abc2f-f83c-4c52-84f9-f10cbae59ada" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="27362882-2d21-47ea-a65a-27102e6dea1e" TYPE="swap"
```

So it is there, but all as read-only and hence I can't use it. How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: The answer by a-donda is spot-on. This means that the error is not an error, just a warning.

Answer (score 3):

[ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) is a read-only file system, because it was designed for read-only media (CD-ROMs). This shouldn't pose a problem for installation though, because during installation the installation medium is only read and not written to.

Mount the image read-only to a folder (e.g. `/mnt`), open a terminal and change the working directory to that folder, then start the installation program. Everything should be fine.

Comment: I did that before, but all I get is a series of Input/output errors. For example   cp: reading '/some/path':Input/output error
  cp: failed to extend '/same/path/as/above':Input/output error   Hence I thought it was related to the mounting error...

Comment: That's strange. Maybe something went wrong while downloading the file? If you're sure that's not the case, it would be good to include a verbatim copy of all the commands you used and all the messages you got in the question. Use the edit link below your question to do so.